# How to move a message from one queue to another queue in tibco keeping same message id and other header info. using c#

Tags: c#, tibco

I have a task to write c# code to move messages from one TIBCO message queue to another queue with same header information including message id. Is this possible to keep same message id while moving messages between queues?. I am able to move messages but not able to keep same message id. Help appreciated

Comment: I think this is impossible. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.id(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: As the MessageID is a unique Identifier, not possible. What is your exact goal for this task? If identifying the message in another context is necessary, it can be done with the JMSCorrelationID. If your task is "simply moving" the original message into another queue without modification actually no #C code is needed, it can be done with a TIBCO EMS bridge by configuration

Comment: Thanks for help. i decided to keep  JMSCorrelationID. It was to identifying the message in another context.